# Ruby on Rails INSERT Error ***** PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation invoices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-insert, psql

I inherited a web app project, and all the implicit magic behind ruby on rails still gets me sometimes. I created two new tables and associated controllers - invoices and invoice_items with one foreign key between them. In my rails app, I get down to the insert when it crashes.

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for relation invoices 

: INSERT INTO "invoices" ("created_at", "invoice_item_id", "quantity", "amount", "description", 
    "person_id", "effective_date", "schedule") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id" 

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:22:in `confirm_bill'
```

I am new to rails / Postgres. I was expecting to see 'permission denied for *table* invoices'. Is the term ***relation*** interchangeable with the term ***table*** in this error context? If not, how do I grant permissions to a relation? I am providing the invoice_item_id so there is no joining with invoice_item needed. I can also do an manual insert on the table when signed in as app_student (the rails user).

There are lots of posts about granting all permissions to the user, but I am trying to follow the principle of least privilege. The app user only needs to insert as another process will pickup the invoices and process them. There is nothing else that I know of that would require additional permissions.

```
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE public.invoices TO app_student;
```

Why is this permission for my ruby on rails user insufficient?

Comment: This really looks like a postgres permissions thing and not a Rails thing actually (error is correct in saying relation it seems https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2018/03/07/How-to-fix-permission-denied-for-relation-some_table_name-in-PostgreSQL)

Comment: @Joel_Blum While I tend to agree with you, I can manually do an insert as the app_student user. There is something more because RoR is involved.

Comment: Whats happening on your databases.yml? Is the user listed there indeed app_student?

Comment: @Joel_Blum Yes, of course, that is where I got the credentials for my manual attempt.

Comment: While I can understand why you feel the way you do, that is absolutely a DB permissions error and has nothing to with the fact that you are using rails. The `pg` gem does not need rails to work (it is not a dependency). This error comes straight from the database (Error Code 42501) as show [Here](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/00cb2ecfaa70470234ee83efbd942b5e6ea0f4ea/ext/errorcodes.txt#L333) and [Here](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/00cb2ecfaa70470234ee83efbd942b5e6ea0f4ea/ext/errorcodes.def#L607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a whim, I granted select permissions to my rails app user. I still do not know why, but that fixed my problem. There must have been some follow up by rails user to see the insert succeeded. Is that more rails 'magic'?

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLE public.invoices TO app_student;
```